# SOLVED Peripherals not working after install of Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, usb, pi-3

I recently purchased a Canakit Raspberry Pi 3 Model B. I hooked it all up using HDMI, ethernet and USB peripherals (no hub). I have a logitech mouse and a dynex keyboard, both want 5V 100mA.

In the Noobs setup application, the mouse and keyboard worked fine. I went ahead and installed Raspbian, being new to this, and let 'er rip. Everything appeared to download and extract correctly and the device rebooted. I noticed in the startup output that I received a "failed to start load kernel modules" but everything else listed with a status of OK.

Here is the output for uname -a:

Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

Here is the output for dmesg:

```
[    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
[    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
[    0.000000] Linux version 4.1.19-v7+ (dc4@dc4-XPS13-9333) (gcc version 4.9.3 (crosstool-NG crosstool-ng-1.22.0-88-g8460611) ) #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016
[    0.000000] CPU: ARMv7 Processor [410fd034] revision 4 (ARMv7), cr=10c5383d
[    0.000000] CPU: PIPT / VIPT nonaliasing data cache, VIPT aliasing instruction cache
[    0.000000] Machine model: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
[    0.000000] cma: Reserved 8 MiB at 0x3a400000
[    0.000000] Memory policy: Data cache writealloc
[    0.000000] On node 0 totalpages: 241664
[    0.000000] free_area_init_node: node 0, pgdat 80880fc0, node_mem_map b9bb4000
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 2124 pages used for memmap
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 0 pages reserved
[    0.000000]   Normal zone: 241664 pages, LIFO batch:31
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] enter (9420->f3003010)
[    0.000000] [bcm2709_smp_init_cpus] ncores=4
[    0.000000] PERCPU: Embedded 12 pages/cpu @bafb0000 s20416 r8192 d20544 u49152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s20416 r8192 d20544 u49152 alloc=12*4096
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 0 [0] 1 [0] 2 [0] 3 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists in Zone order, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 239540
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: 8250.nr_uarts=1 dma.dmachans=0x7f35 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=1824 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=984 bcm2709.boardrev=0xa02082 bcm2709.serial=0xf9805c06 smsc95xx.macaddr=B8:27:EB:80:5C:06 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 bcm2709.uart_clock=48000000 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3dc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x3f000000  dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyS0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p7 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
[    0.000000] PID hash table entries: 4096 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 131072 (order: 7, 524288 bytes)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes)
[    0.000000] Memory: 939376K/966656K available (6064K kernel code, 534K rwdata, 1664K rodata, 444K init, 757K bss, 19088K reserved, 8192K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] Virtual kernel memory layout:
    vector  : 0xffff0000 - 0xffff1000   (   4 kB)
    fixmap  : 0xffc00000 - 0xfff00000   (3072 kB)
    vmalloc : 0xbb800000 - 0xff000000   (1080 MB)
    lowmem  : 0x80000000 - 0xbb000000   ( 944 MB)
    modules : 0x7f000000 - 0x80000000   (  16 MB)
      .text : 0x80008000 - 0x807945f0   (7730 kB)
      .init : 0x80795000 - 0x80804000   ( 444 kB)
      .data : 0x80804000 - 0x80889b10   ( 535 kB)
       .bss : 0x8088c000 - 0x809497dc   ( 758 kB)
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=4, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000]  Additional per-CPU info printed with stalls.
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS:608
[    0.000000] Architected cp15 timer(s) running at 19.20MHz (phys).
[    0.000000] clocksource arch_sys_counter: mask: 0xffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x46d987e47, max_idle_ns: 440795202767 ns
[    0.000008] sched_clock: 56 bits at 19MHz, resolution 52ns, wraps every 4398046511078ns
[    0.000025] Switching to timer-based delay loop, resolution 52ns
[    0.000246] Console: colour dummy device 80x30
[    0.001291] console [tty1] enabled
[    0.001344] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 38.40 BogoMIPS (lpj=192000)
[    0.001412] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001730] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.001773] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes)
[    0.002763] Initializing cgroup subsys blkio
[    0.002815] Initializing cgroup subsys memory
[    0.002862] Initializing cgroup subsys devices
[    0.002905] Initializing cgroup subsys freezer
[    0.002955] Initializing cgroup subsys net_cls
[    0.003026] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003113] ftrace: allocating 20313 entries in 60 pages
[    0.048389] CPU0: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.048454] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.048487] [bcm2709_smp_prepare_cpus] enter
[    0.048641] Setting up static identity map for 0x8240 - 0x8274
[    0.050406] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:1 started (0) 17
[    0.050610] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:1
[    0.050651] CPU1: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.050658] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.051044] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:2 started (0) 17
[    0.051210] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:2
[    0.051232] CPU2: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.051238] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.051600] [bcm2709_boot_secondary] cpu:3 started (0) 18
[    0.051732] [bcm2709_secondary_init] enter cpu:3
[    0.051752] CPU3: update cpu_capacity 1024
[    0.051759] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.051821] Brought up 4 CPUs
[    0.051919] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (153.60 BogoMIPS).
[    0.051949] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.051975] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.052674] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.071379] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 3 rev 4
[    0.071660] clocksource jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.072502] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.073057] NET: Registered protocol family 16
[    0.078180] DMA: preallocated 4096 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.079162] bcm2709.uart_clock = 48000000
[    0.083238] bcm2709: Mini UART enabled
[    0.083305] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.083352] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.083526] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.083590] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: could not find pctldev for node /soc/gpio@7e200000/uart0_pins, deferring probe
[    0.083786] bcm2835-mbox 3f00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.149105] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager at f3007000, dmachans=0xf35
[    0.149176] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: Initialized 7 DMA channels (+ 1 legacy)
[    0.149769] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: Load BCM2835 DMA engine driver
[    0.149805] bcm2708-dmaengine 3f007000.dma: dma_debug:0
[    0.150379] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.150589] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.150703] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.150823] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.151367] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2016-03-15 14:47
[    0.178466] Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.219929] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.220220] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.229566] NET: Registered protocol family 2
[    0.230535] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes)
[    0.230675] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.230886] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.231000] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.231069] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes)
[    0.231398] NET: Registered protocol family 1
[    0.231722] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.231754] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.231782] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.231809] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.232765] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    0.233838] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes)
[    0.247215] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.247546] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.249677] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    0.250597] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    0.250660] Key type id_resolver registered
[    0.250688] Key type id_legacy registered
[    0.252764] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 252)
[    0.252940] io scheduler noop registered
[    0.252979] io scheduler deadline registered (default)
[    0.253268] io scheduler cfq registered
[    0.255544] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA memory fa800000
[    0.255591] BCM2708FB: allocated DMA channel 0 @ f3007000
[    0.282119] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 228x61
[    0.297551] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 1 ports, IRQ sharing disabled
[    0.299164] console [ttyS0] disabled
[    0.299283] 3f215040.uart: ttyS0 at MMIO 0x3f215040 (irq = 29, base_baud = 50000000) is a 16550
[    1.496167] console [ttyS0] enabled
[    1.502816] vc-cma: Videocore CMA driver
[    1.509274] vc-cma: vc_cma_base      = 0x00000000
[    1.516969] vc-cma: vc_cma_size      = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.525819] vc-cma: vc_cma_initial   = 0x00000000 (0 MiB)
[    1.534822] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3dc00000 mem_size:0x3f000000(1008 MiB)
[    1.559726] brd: module loaded
[    1.571713] loop: module loaded
[    1.577687] vchiq: vchiq_init_state: slot_zero = 0xba880000, is_master = 0
[    1.590543] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.599222] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.608684] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.818375] Core Release: 2.80a
[    1.823538] Setting default values for core params
[    1.831419] Finished setting default values for core params
[    2.040892] Using Buffer DMA mode
[    2.046316] Periodic Transfer Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.055878] Multiprocessor Interrupt Enhancement - disabled
[    2.065012] OTG VER PARAM: 0, OTG VER FLAG: 0
[    2.072222] Dedicated Tx FIFOs mode
[    2.078209] WARN::dwc_otg_hcd_init:1047: FIQ DMA bounce buffers: virt = 0xba814000 dma = 0xfa814000 len=9024
[    2.094336] FIQ FSM acceleration enabled for :
Non-periodic Split Transactions
Periodic Split Transactions
High-Speed Isochronous Endpoints
[    2.134180] dwc_otg: Microframe scheduler enabled
[    2.134232] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:412: FIQ on core 1 at 0x80417288
[    2.148069] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:413: FIQ ASM at 0x804175f8 length 36
[    2.162441] WARN::hcd_init_fiq:438: MPHI regs_base at 0xbb89c000
[    2.176407] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.188671] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    2.204770] dwc_otg 3f980000.usb: irq 32, io mem 0x00000000
[    2.218029] Init: Port Power? op_state=1
[    2.228557] Init: Power Port (0)
[    2.238126] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    2.253411] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    2.269408] usb usb1: Product: DWC OTG Controller
[    2.281270] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 4.1.19-v7+ dwc_otg_hcd
[    2.295225] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 3f980000.usb
[    2.307531] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.317783] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    2.328615] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    2.328624] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    2.328632] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    2.328664] Module dwc_common_port init
[    2.328931] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.342969] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    2.356781] bcm2835-cpufreq: min=600000 max=1200000
[    2.369093] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    2.383286] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    2.394760] sdhost: log_buf @ ba813000 (fa813000)
[    2.478500] mmc0: sdhost-bcm2835 loaded - DMA enabled (>1)
[    2.513884] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    2.518572] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
[    2.539959] mmc-bcm2835 3f300000.mmc: DMA channel allocated
[    2.559544] mmc0: host does not support reading read-only switch, assuming write-enable
[    2.579649] mmc0: new high speed SDHC card at address 0001
[    2.588588] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    2.588962] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    2.589086] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    2.589281] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.589283] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.589690] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    2.589715] NET: Registered protocol family 17
[    2.589829] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    2.590260] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    2.590911] registered taskstats version 1
[    2.591092] vc-sm: Videocore shared memory driver
[    2.591101] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    2.593093] [vc_sm_connected_init]: end - returning 0
[    2.594449] 3f201000.uart: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0x3f201000 (irq = 83, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    2.708502] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using dwc_otg
[    2.712921] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
[    2.793028] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk0p7...
[    2.793291] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SD32G 29.3 GiB 
[    2.799703]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 < p5 p6 p7 >
[    2.816405] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (2 bytes)
[    2.818003] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.819583] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (3 bytes)
[    2.822403] mmc1: queuing unknown CIS tuple 0x80 (7 bytes)
[    2.882796] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[    2.898608] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): write access will be enabled during recovery
[    2.898809] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
[    2.898819] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.899494] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.899586] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
[    2.913601] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    3.178534] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 3 using dwc_otg
[    3.288758] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00
[    3.304009] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    3.322611] smsc95xx v1.0.4
[    3.391533] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-3f980000.usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet, b8:27:eb:80:5c:06
[    3.544794] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): orphan cleanup on readonly fs
[    3.558739] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): 1 orphan inode deleted
[    3.571330] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): recovery complete
[    3.638343] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    3.655642] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:7.
[    3.683461] devtmpfs: mounted
[    3.693088] Freeing unused kernel memory: 444K (80795000 - 80804000)
[    4.090324] random: systemd urandom read with 56 bits of entropy available
[    4.109467] systemd[1]: systemd 215 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +SYSVINIT +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +ACL +XZ -SECCOMP -APPARMOR)
[    4.136046] systemd[1]: Detected architecture 'arm'.
[    4.214406] systemd[1]: Failed to insert module 'ipv6'
[    4.229090] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <raspberrypi>.
[    4.695053] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyS0.device...
[    4.714156] systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.731274] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    4.748087] systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.766694] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems (Pre).
[    4.781156] systemd[1]: Starting Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.805484] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    4.825423] systemd[1]: Starting Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.843325] systemd[1]: Reached target Encrypted Volumes.
[    4.856775] systemd[1]: Starting Swap.
[    4.872864] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    4.884471] systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-mmcblk0p6.device...
[    4.904349] systemd[1]: Starting Root Slice.
[    4.921344] systemd[1]: Created slice Root Slice.
[    4.933622] systemd[1]: Starting User and Session Slice.
[    4.952349] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    4.966338] systemd[1]: Starting /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    4.987306] systemd[1]: Listening on /dev/initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    5.003440] systemd[1]: Starting Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    5.022724] systemd[1]: Listening on Delayed Shutdown Socket.
[    5.036925] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.056509] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    5.071023] systemd[1]: Starting udev Control Socket.
[    5.089784] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    5.103456] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.122013] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    5.135554] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Socket.
[    5.153370] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    5.166235] systemd[1]: Starting System Slice.
[    5.183738] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[    5.196380] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    5.219135] systemd[1]: Starting system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    5.239429] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    5.254293] systemd[1]: Starting system-autologin.slice.
[    5.273882] systemd[1]: Created slice system-autologin.slice.
[    5.287915] systemd[1]: Starting system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.307740] systemd[1]: Created slice system-serial\x2dgetty.slice.
[    5.322731] systemd[1]: Starting Increase datagram queue length...
[    5.345724] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    5.373938] systemd[1]: Mounted Huge Pages File System.
[    5.387437] systemd[1]: Starting udev Coldplug all Devices...
[    5.409862] systemd[1]: Mounting Debug File System...
[    5.430290] systemd[1]: Started Create list of required static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    5.481823] systemd[1]: Started Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[    5.496630] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    5.519288] systemd[1]: Starting Create Static Device Nodes in /dev...
[    5.583422] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    5.605518] systemd[1]: Starting Slices.
[    5.623755] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    5.643894] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    5.664847] systemd[1]: Mounted Debug File System.
[    5.684202] systemd[1]: Started Increase datagram queue length.
[    5.756004] systemd[1]: Started Restore / save the current clock.
[    5.771725] systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
[    5.804558] systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
[    5.818822] systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
[    5.841999] systemd[1]: Started udev Coldplug all Devices.
[    5.866388] systemd[1]: Time has been changed
[    5.918209] systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
[    5.952123] systemd[1]: Started File System Check on Root Device.
[    6.060364] systemd[1]: Starting udev Kernel Device Manager...
[    6.083263] systemd[1]: Mounting Configuration File System...
[    6.105990] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    6.120494] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    6.135333] systemd-udevd[99]: starting version 215
[    6.155400] systemd[1]: Starting Syslog Socket.
[    6.173500] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    6.186283] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    6.213634] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[   12.448576] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p7): re-mounted. Opts: (null)
[   12.691713] systemd-journald[103]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[   15.486347] uart-pl011 3f201000.uart: no DMA platform data
[   15.762224] Adding 102396k swap on /var/swap.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:102396k SSFS
[   16.069738] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
[   17.097268] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
[   17.659898] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: link up, 100Mbps, full-duplex, lpa 0xCDE1
[   22.657437] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[  263.718502] usb 1-1.4: new low-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
[  263.835485] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=1267, idProduct=0103
[  263.835506] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[  263.849532] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.0/0003:1267:0103.0001/input/input0
[  263.908772] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [HID 1267:0103] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input0
[  263.922717] input: HID 1267:0103 as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.4/1-1.4:1.1/0003:1267:0103.0002/input/input1
[  263.978748] hid-generic 0003:1267:0103.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Device [HID 1267:0103] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.4/input1
[  269.608506] usb 1-1.5: new low-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
[  269.726383] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c044
[  269.726401] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  269.726415] usb 1-1.5: Product: USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse
[  269.726428] usb 1-1.5: Manufacturer: Logitech
[  269.746702] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/platform/soc/3f980000.usb/usb1/1-1/1-1.5/1-1.5:1.0/0003:046D:C044.0003/input/input2
[  269.747119] hid-generic 0003:046D:C044.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-3f980000.usb-1.5/input0
```

GUI loads. Mouse and keyboard are completely non-functional. They are so non-functional that holding shift down during boot now does not enter recovery mode, just gets me back to the GUI with the same load error on boot and unusable peripherals.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

First, if they're USB ones - re-plug them after the boot is over. If it does not help at all - try using an externally powered USB hub, replugging a hub may also help. It's a rare but typical issue for Linux systems, I meet it from time to time. Can you SSH into your RPi3? If you can, please send an output of `uname -a` and **full** `dmesg` - so I will be able to help you further

Comment: Here is the log for dmesg: It was too long for this comment, I have added to the end of my question. Thanks for your help! Tried a reboot without peripherals, attached a good five minutes after boot, no effect. Don't have a powered hub, will need to try that later.

Comment: Hi Alexey, thank you for taking the time to help me out. Turns out I had old drivers on the distro. Running sudo rpi-update fixed it.

Comment: an old kernel/drivers/sysctl's were my primary suspects =) I'm glad to help

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had old drivers on the MicroSD card for this distro of Raspberian. The following link helped me to identify the problems: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=53832

It required running `sudo rpi-update` after a reboot everything is up and running!

Comment: Please accept your answer with a click on the tick on its left side. That will finish the question and it will not pop up again also after years.